# How to build Shim from source

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to build [shim](https://github.com/rhboot/shim) from source but i'm getting the following error.

```
ld -o shimx64.so --hash-style=sysv -nostdlib -znocombreloc -T /home/john/git/shim/elf_x86_64_efi.lds -shared -Bsymbolic -L/usr/lib64/gnuefi -L/usr/lib64 -LCryptlib -LCryptlib/OpenSSL /usr/lib64/gnuefi/crt0-efi-x86_64.o --build-id=sha1  --no-undefined shim.o mok.o netboot.o cert.o replacements.o tpm.o version.o errlog.o Cryptlib/libcryptlib.a Cryptlib/OpenSSL/libopenssl.a lib/lib.a -lefi -lgnuefi --start-group Cryptlib/libcryptlib.a Cryptlib/OpenSSL/libopenssl.a --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/gnuefi/crt0-efi-x86_64.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find -lefi
ld: cannot find -lgnuefi
make: *** [Makefile:92: shimx64.so] Error 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

### My environment

**System**

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**Packages**

- `build-essential`
- `make`
- `gnu-efi`

## Update

Thomas answer helped me build but when running

```sh
make EFIDIR=/boot/efi install
```

I get the following error

```sh
gcc -Og -g3 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -o buildid /home/john/git/shim/buildid.c -lelf
/home/john/git/shim/buildid.c:15:10: fatal error: libelf.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <libelf.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:117: buildid] Error 1
```

Tried adding the same variables as per Thomas answer but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gnu-efi/filelist) of the `gnu-efi` package, I see:

```
/usr/lib/crt0-efi-x86_64.o (not /usr/lib64/gnuefi/crt0-efi-x86_64.o)
/usr/lib/libefi.a (not in /usr/lib64)
/usr/lib/libgnuefi.a (not in /usr/lib64)
```

I think you need to set `LIBDIR=/usr/lib` and `EFI_PATH=/usr/lib` during `make`, rather than the defaults which are `/usr/lib64` (set [here](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/edc08062f1bea137ab5f2efae6c0b7d0ddaecd57/Make.defaults#L49)) and `/usr/lib64/gnuefi` (set [here](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/edc08062f1bea137ab5f2efae6c0b7d0ddaecd57/Make.defaults#L115)).

Comment: This worked, I'm now able to build, thanks a lot!

Comment: I ran in to another error when running `make install`, presumably of the same nature but couldn't figure it out. Would you able to look at it (put my question in my original post as an update)?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, `libelf.h` is [provided](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libelf.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any) by the `libelf-dev` package.

Comment: Yes that did it, my hero;)